# Fulltext search in inner join table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, inner-join

I've this query:

`SELECT r.*, rtype.type as type FROM`app_resource`r
INNER JOIN`app_resource_type`rtype ON rtype.id = r.resource_type_id
WHERE MATCH(`name`,`type`) AGAINST('abcdef' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

This query results:

`#1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH`

What is wrong? Both columns have a full-text index!

Comment: I think `name,type` are from different tables ?

Comment: Yes, it are from different tables.

Comment: So is the problem you can not have one match with fields from different tables, you may need to split it into two `match(name) against ... and/or match(type) against...`